# How to make a horizontal scrolling character chooser in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I have been looking online for the best way to do this but I can't figure it out. I am trying to make a horizontal scrolling character chooser like in this example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYWYR.jpg), and its hard to tell from just a picture but you can drag your finger left and right and it will get scroll over to the other characters.

I just need to add images of each character, and if it isn't too much harder then maybe a label with the name of the character under it, and a touch gesture recognizer of some sort to select a character when you tap on it.

Originally I was thinking of using a Scrollview with a horizontal stack view in it that stacks UIViews from the left to the right. Inside each UIView is the characters image with its name on a label under it. But I am also wondering if it would be easier with a collection view instead?

I can't seem to figure out how to add the views to a side scrolling scrollview and make the tap gestures recognize it, if anybody has any input on how I would do this that would be awesome!

Also would using a collection view or stack view be better? Or even another way using SpriteKit that I don't know about? Basically any input to point me in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you are using Sprite Kit to develop a game, it will be best to stay away from UIKit stuff like `UIScrollView` and `UICollectionView`.  I wouldn't even use `Timer`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what is the best way for me to do this then only using SpriteKit? I can't seem to find anything online besides UIKit stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do well to avoid using UIKit classes in SpriteKit, just because it's just a different beast. Additionally, SpriteKit uses its own game time, so you wouldn't want to rely on some other time if for example your game is paused for whatever reason.

I typically build my own components, which would be how I would approach this challenge as well. You should make a custom SKNode subclass, let's say *Picker*, the instance of which you embed onto the SKScene. Within that component, you'll handle touches independently from the SKScene and program in tapping, dragging and dropping behavior, natively. SKAction animations will help in snapping the correct "page" selection into place after a drop.

So then, whenever the component detects a tap or a swiped selection (the end of a drag: drop), it sends a signal either to your data or the SKScene parent, telling that the selection should be updated.

I'm sure there might be third-party components around, but I would invest time into this sort of development, if you plan on sticking with SpriteKit. You will typically need to get into the weeds of things, but that's part of the fun :).

I'm happy to help further, if needed.